# in a select query, getting the count of something from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

table 'members' : id username
and
table 'posts' : poster

What I want is an array including id, username and number of the posts the member has posted.(for each member)

I couldn't write the right query for this.

Comment: Please show us the data structure or setup a SQL fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.username, COUNT(p.id)
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON m.id = p.memberid
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT id, username, 
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM posts 
     WHERE poster = id) 
as count FROM members
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT m.ID,m.username,count(p.numberOfPosts) as Counter FROM members m join posts p where m.ID=p.memberid Group by m.ID;
```